# Xstream creating classes and causing painful permgen collections

Tags: java, garbage-collection, xstream, permgen

I'm having an issue where classes generated by Xstreams xstream.fromXML(xmlString) method are causing our web container to undergo painful garbage collections from the permgen filling up. It caused one of our resin 3.2.1 servers to become unresponsive, forcing a restart.

I tried using different Xstream drivers such as jdom, dom4j, DomDriver, xpp, and jettison with no luck.

The classes generated have names like sun.reflect.GeneratedSerializationConstructorAccessor23

Anyone know if it is possible to avoid this or is this an unavoidable side effect of the current Xstream implementation (1.4.2)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that we are creating a new instance of XStream every request. It is designed to be multi-threaded and caches generated classes. Converting it to a static instance fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CMS collector, you could enable background collection of perm gen with `-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled` option.
Also increasing perm gen size should be helpful `-XX:MaxPermSize=N`. You can find more GC related options in [this cheat sheet](http://blog.ragozin.info/2011/09/hotspot-jvm-garbage-collection-options.html).

Though it is tuning of JVM GC, not fix XStream problem.

Comment: Increasing the permgen size would most likely make the problem worse since there would be even more classes to clean up. XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled is also on by default in Java 6 as far as I can tell, our classes are getting GC'd properly. The problem is that when the GC runs it can lock up the whole jvm for a while.

Comment: @Nash0 **1.** Background class unloading is off for CMS collector by default
**2.** More perm space -> more time between pauses -> less time spent in GC (compared to application time).